# How to display variable value with use of javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

In @variable.value i have a string containing html tags, i.e. `<b>aaa</b>`. I want to display this text on a page - hmtl tags should not be displayed as strings but should format the text.

I am not convinced to use of methods: raw or html_safe.

I would like to display @variable.value on show page with use of javascript.

I've tried:

show.html:

```
<script>
document.write('<%= @variable.value %>'); #-> <b>aaa</b>
</script>
```

but if i try:

```
document.write('<b>aaa</b>'); #this works, i get "aaa" bolded
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in the console with console.log or someHTMLElement.innerHTML =

Answer (score 0):

following code is working (displays properly formatted text):

```
<class id="content" data-text="<%= @variable.value %>"></class>
<script>
  var text = $("#content").data("text");
  document.write(text);
</script>
```